# Radchart shrinks inside Radtab

Tags: telerik, telerik-charting

We have 3 tab RadTabStrip and each of the tab has radtabs. We have radchart inside these tabs.

The chart gets loaded correctly onload. But it gets shrinked when i move from one tab to other.

I have noticed that 'd' attribute in 'path' element inside the 'g' element('svg') of radchart gets changed on moving from tabs to tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes down to sizing.  The width and height (you are using percentages, are you not) are not always passed down from one container to the next.  You will have to explicitly add Height and width to each container.  Then your charts and grids will shape up correctly.